# Toolbar implementation using a method from another class

Tags: java, android

I would like my MainActivity class to be more transparent, so instead of in MainAcitivty class in the onCreate method, implement the Toolbar in the following way:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

I've created a new SetToolbar class with one method:

```
class SetToolbar extends AppCompatActivity {

    void methodToolbar() {

        Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

And then the method I wanted to call in the MainActivity class in the onCreate method:

```
SetToolbar test = new SetToolbar();
test.methodToolbar();
```

Is there such a thing possible? I do not know what to think about it, because I do not receive any information about the error, but the application does not want to turn on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean, but I guess you want to avoid useless code in your MainActivity.
What you did is not very good, it's better to make MainActivity inherit from the BaseActivity that you badly called SetToolbar.

So create your mother activity

```
class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void methodToolbar() {

        Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

And your MainActivity

```
class MainActivity extends BaseActivity 
  onCreate(){
    ...
    methodToolbar()
    ...
  }
```

in the layout of MainActivity, you have to add toolbar layout, or even create another layout and add it in all your activities by .
And don't forget to declare your activities in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant, now everything works fine, but let's assume that I would like to do the same with another thing. The MainActivity class is already extended by the BaseActivity class, so I can no longer extend it with any additional class. So what could I do to make it a good practice. Create a new X class, and then extend the BaseActivity class by class X?

Comment: I forgot to tell you to set BaseActivity as abstract. You can add other methods in BaseActivity, even if they'll not be used by lots of activities. It's a good way to write generical methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try this, First thing, edit your SetToolBar class to be like this

```
class SetToolbar  {
    Context context;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    public SetToolbar(Context context, Toolbar toolbar)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.toolbar = toolbar;
    }

void methodToolbar() {
       ((AppCompatActivity)context).setSupportActionBar(this.toolbar);
       ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

And in your MainAcivity in onCreate()

```
new SetToolbar(getBaseContext(), (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar)).methodToolbar();
```